# Return hidden field with $_POST out of multiple if file is uploaded

Tags: php

```
<form class="formp" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm" name="wjd">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"/>
<p>Gerecht:</p><p>Prijs:</p><p>Plaatje:</p><p>Upload:</p>
<?php
$resultmenus = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM prijslijst WHERE menunaam='menu\'s'");
while($rowmenus = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmenus,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 echo   "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"{$rowmenus['id']}\"/>";
 echo   "<input name=\"gerecht[]\" type=\"text\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"30\" value=\"{$rowmenus['gerecht']}\"/>";
 echo   "<input name=\"prijs[]\" type=\"text\" size=\"5\" maxlength=\"5\" value=\"{$rowmenus['prijs']}\"/>";
 echo   "<img src=\"../{$rowmenus['plaatje']}\" /><input  size=\"1\" type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" id=\"file\"/>";
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="verzend" />
</form>
```

This will output a form with id's 1 to 5 from the db echo'd in the hidden input type field.
My question is: when i upload only 1 file in row 3 with id3 and the rest are empty, is it possible to retrieve only that id?

Because when i try to retrieve it with $_POST['id']; I get the last value which is 5.The is the output to the browser.

```
<form id="frm" class="formp" name="wjd" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="2000000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<p>Gerecht:</p><p>Prijs:</p><p>Plaatje:</p><p>Upload:</p>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">
<input type="text" value="Menu 1" maxlength="30" size="30" name="gerecht[]">
<input type="text" value="3.00" maxlength="5" size="5" name="prijs[]">
<img src="../images/plaatjes/mini_menu3.gif">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" size="1">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="id">
<input type="text" value="Menu 2" maxlength="30" size="30" name="gerecht[]">
<input type="text" value="6.00" maxlength="5" size="5" name="prijs[]">
<img src="../images/plaatjes/mini_menu2.gif">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" size="1">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="id">
<input type="text" value="Menu 3" maxlength="30" size="30" name="gerecht[]">
<input type="text" value="6.00" maxlength="5" size="5" name="prijs[]">
<img src="../images/plaatjes/mini_menu1.gif">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" size="1">
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="id">
<input type="text" value="Menu 4" maxlength="30" size="30" name="gerecht[]">
<input type="text" value="7.00" maxlength="5" size="5" name="prijs[]">
<img src="../images/plaatjes/mini_menu3.gif">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" size="1">
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="id">
<input type="text" value="Menu 5" maxlength="30" size="30" name="gerecht[]">
<input type="text" value="4.00" maxlength="5" size="5" name="prijs[]">
<img src="../images/plaatjes/mini_menu2.gif">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" size="1">
<input type="submit" value="verzend" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is the handling script.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if((array_search('', $_POST["gerecht"])!==false) or (array_search('', $_POST["prijs"])!==false)) { //1 or more field empty
        echo "<span class=\"error\">Please fill in all fields</span>";
        exit();
    }else{//field filled in



       foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $i => $name) {

            if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$i] == 4) { // no upload continue
                continue;
            }
            if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$i] == 0) {

                echo $_POST['id'];


            }//end else error 0

       }//end foreach 
    }//end filled in forms

}else{ //submit button clicked


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you re-use a form element name (and it's not an array) the last value will overwrite previous values.  See how you have

```
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="id">
```

try instead

```
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="id[]">
```

and iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="id">
```

etc.

You're going to only get number 5 because it is the last one, and is overwriting the one before it.

Same with the input texts, the `name` attribute should be different.

Do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see all that is being POST'ed.